# Which are the things like that, which have or has that effect(i. e., death or else 100% confirmed permanent paralysis for sure for life) like that?

Tags: chemistry, biochemistry, medical, poisons, pharmacology

I want to build a world but an element of the world is causing me problem and that element is that I need such a "thing" or a group of the "things" with which a person laces a food item of a "STRONG MAN" and just after taking that food item or the ingestible thing he(i. e., the strong man) has a desire to sleep and sleeps. He does not feel the symptoms vomiting, "head revolving", dizziness etc. Instead he "SLEEPS". Just after lying on the bed he dies within 3-4 minutes. "Even if he survives in any case, he must be permanently paralyzed for life 100% confirmed for sure." Which are the things like that(with which the ingestible thing of the strong man has been laced), which have or has that effect(i. e., death or  else 100% confirmed permanent paralysis for sure for life) like that? Those thing(s) and/or the poison(s) should be either:

1. available at a shop;

Or

2. should be makeable at home.

Note: The Strong Man has to be killed. Or permanently paralyzed for life. No other choice.
Dear friends, if you think 3-4 minutes are very less for any type of poisoning to kill, you can also tell the thing(s) or the poison(s) which take a little bit more time to kill(more than 3-4 minutes, i. e., say      ...  upto 15-20 minutes; not more than that(after lying on the bed)).

Comment: I hope you don't mind me for saying it, but this sounds phishy :/ What have you found so far and why doesn't it satisfy your needs?

Comment: That was my first thought as well -- we're not here to help plan a murder.

Comment: mmm, taking into account how he wrote his question, and his last two questions -which are also about poisoning- I would think it twice before answering.

Comment: His question on gardening SE is related to growing strychnine producing plants. I'm sure he's being watched, on a list with the right people.

Comment: Dear Duckisaduckisaduck,
                  No offense.My question in gardening SE was on Farming(Gardening) and that was on my own safety(that is,I me myself would die if I do not farm correctly).Moreover, the famous Homeopathic Medicine "NUX VOMICA" is made up of this tree only.I asked questions on Worldbuilding SE on poisoning because I had seen other fiction writers asking questions on poisoning.Nobody uses bitter plant nux-vomica to kill.Still I am extremely sorry if I hurted your sentiments,I have voted to delete the question(my own question),although worldbuilding SE does not prefer it.

Comment: Homeopathic medicines are notoriously made only by sugar. That aside, this question cannot be deleted because it has an answer which has been voted, and deleting the question would be unfair to the poster of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For story or game purposes, the item you're looking for is called "poison".  You need not specify exactly what it is unless you're writing a murder mystery or your name is Tom Clancy (or equivalent).  Otherwise, for most action of fantasy purposes, you can either just call it a "fast-acting paralytic poison that often kills the victim" or you can make up a name: "The Mordu tribe, near the headwaters of the River Tarnak, make an extract of the vordin root that paralyzes in a minute or two, and kills most."